# Reasonably priced Internet-controlled power outlet?

Tags: power-control, remote-control

I have a peripheral (and occasionally a home server) that hangs and I have to power cycle them to get them to respond again.  I know there are corporate-targeted power strips with the ability to turn outlets on/off over the Internet, but they are usually $150+ which is out of my price range for convenience at home.  Are there power strips for less than $40 that can be controlled over the Internet?

I could get by with only single on/off control (one outlet or the whole strip), but of course, multiple outlet control would be awesome.

This particular device is inside my firewall, but the ability to 'reset' the outlet rather than just turn on or off would allow me to use it on the firewall as well.

Comment: How many outlets are you looking to control, and do you need independent control of them? Also, does your LAN maintain Internet connectivity when your server dies (or does this device need to sit outside your firewall?)

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1495/

Comment: I don't know of any specific piece of hardware, but a DIY solution could possibly be done cheaply. I have a set of three remote controlled power relays which cost me less than 20$. With a bit of soldering I imagine the remote control could be hooked up to GPIO pins on a cheap single-board computer.

Answer (score 5):

The Quirky PPVG-WH01 Pivot Power Genius is network controllable.  There are mobile device apps for controlling it.  If I remember correctly it's based on Electric Imp so it should be easy to write your own apps to control it.  It's < $65.

Also check out the Ankuoo Neo, YW Smart Plug, KanKun Smart Plug, and Broadlink Smart plug.  All are < $30.